# Unzipping files - paths

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to unzip a file in Java and add all the contents to an array list rather than write to a disk. The issue I am having is that I pass in a certain path to a zip file and then when it reads the zip file and adds the file to the list - when I come to process the files they have strange paths inside my project directory which do not exist.

Please can someone help me here?
    public void processZipFile(String path) {

```
    File file = new File(path);
    file.setReadable(true);
    ZipFile zip;
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        zip = new ZipFile(file);
        Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = (Enumeration<ZipEntry>) zip
                .entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            File f = new java.io.File(entry.getName());
            allFiles.add(f);
        }
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"strange paths"*  Vague description.  What paths are in the Zip?  What is the root of the extract path?  What types of paths did you expect?  What type of paths did you get? ..

Comment: Note: If you're using Java SE 7, consider to use the new NIO File API to work with files and Zip files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your `entry.getName()` won't return anything useful that can be used to open a file. Remember that this is just a zip entry and not a physical file.
I would suggest you to store the inputStreams for every entry in you array using [zipFile.getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) and then extract your contents from the inputstream and finally close these streams when they are useless to you.